# finding hour difference between two times in php not working

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have 2 times in my sql table like 02:56:07pm and 03:56:14pm, so i converted it like:

```
$time1 = date("G:i:s", strtotime($row['timein']));
$time2 = date("G:i:s", strtotime($row['timeout']));
```

which gives me two times like 14:56:07 and 15:56:14

now am trying to find the difference in hours between this two times and I did like below:

```
$difference = round(abs($time2 - $time1) / 3600,2);
echo $difference;
```

but here am getting 0 as answer

Comment: You are trying to do calculations with formatted time strings like `"14:56:07"`. String don't magically convert back to timestamps with math functions. You probably meant to calculate with the results of `strtotime()`, not `date()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me:

Using [strtotime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) that converts a date/time string into a Unix Timestamp (eg. 163612416703). Now calculations can be done on the times.

```
$time1 = strtotime('02:56:07pm');
$time2 = strtotime('05:56:14pm');

$difference = date('H:i:s', ($time2 - $time1));
echo $difference; //03:00:07
```

Play around with the formatting etc..

Comment: Better to use gmdate(). With date an incorrect result is generated if the default time zone is not UTC.